# How to create a fixed non-scrolling ap div in DW cs4

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am trying to create a header panel in Dreamweaver cs 4  that does not scroll along with other content on page - I want it to remain always visible along the top.

Thank you in advance

Comment: this has nothing to do with dreamweaver...

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: what are you talking about? explain the issue well & add some 'code' or 'fiddle' so we may help u fix the issue....

Answer (score -1):

In Dreamweaver you can select the header div. Then in the CSS styles window you can click "Edit rule" and select the positing category. In the first box labeled position you can select "Fixed".

Or the more appropriate way would be to directly edit your CSS with the following.

```
#divID {
position:fixed;
}
```